# how to copy the row value as per row name into another row using pyhton

Tags: python

```
Field_Name = ['Field Name', 'Success', 'Failure', '%']
thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=Field_Name)
# thewriter.writeheader()
thewriter.writerow({'Field Name': 'Extraction Accuracy', '%': extraction_accuracy})
thewriter.writerow({'Field Name': 'Classification Accuracy', '%': " "})
```

i want to copy "DOC-TYPE", % row value into "Classification Accuracy"

[image]

Comment: You need to read the csv into a variable first.  Can you provide a copy of the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

- You just read the original data from the file.
- extract the value from the `DOC-Type` row
- insert value into the `Classification Accuracy` row
- write the data back to same file

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

with open(csvfile) as csvf:  
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvf)  # read data from csv file
    for row in reader:
        # find "DOC-TYPE" row and get value of "%"
        if row["Field Name"] == "DOC-TYPE":
            value = row["%"]  # assign value to `value`
            break
    # find "Classif.. Acc.." row and set the "%" key's value to `value`
    for row in reader:
        if row["Field Name"] == "Classification Accuracy":
            row["%"] = value  # copy value into this cell
            break


# then you would just write back to the same file
Field_Name = ['Field Name', 'Success', 'Failure', '%']
with open(csvfile, 'wt') as csvf:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvf, fieldnames=Field_Name)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

For further info on the `csv.DictReader` see the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to read the file and get the row pf DOC-TYPE. When you found the row you can extract the value and paste it to your new row.
I am not aware of any other way to get the row by the first entry, than reading through the file until you found it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

If your current rows are fixed in space (that is, immutable in order), you can do the follwing:

```
list_read = csv.reader(f)
current_list = list(list_read)
desired_value = current_list[13][-1]
# Or it could be current_list[-3][-1] if all the rows depicted finish until 15
```

Finally, proceed to use:

```
thewriter.writerow({'Field Name': 'Classification Accuracy', '%': desired_value })
```

Hope that this could be of use :)